Primefaces Schedule component demo link Broken
Primefaces Schedule component demo link Broken.
Anyone have an idea on what's happening?
Cannot find version 12 in Github
Thanks

Yes it looks like the PF showcase is broken but its working here at the QuarkusFaces showcase: https://quarkus-faces-melloware-8a6a34c1.koyeb.app/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml
If you need version 12.0 of PF its right here in GitHub: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/12.0.0
